# FirebaseUI pod install error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase

My Podfile:

```
pod 'FirebaseUI'
```

When I `pod install` it shows following warning:

[!] Unable to read the license file `/ProjectPath/Pods/FirebaseUI/LICENSE` for the spec `FirebaseUI (0.4.0)`

It shows the same warning in the code samples that Firebase provided. And Where ever I try to use

```
import FirebaseUI
```

It will report no module found. 
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FirebaseUI engineer here:

We went ahead and changed the module name (oops) to FirebaseDatabaseUI (and FirebaseAuthUI, etc.). Working on fixing this ASAP. For now:

```
import FirebaseDatabaseUI
```

and

```
import FirebaseAuthUI
```

where necessary.

The license files will also be updated as well, but it's just a spurious warning.

Comment: Thank you it is solved now. Firebase is awesome. And the new update is making me too excited. I am firebase user from quite a while. The documentation section were quite lacking previously. Hope this has changed with the new site. :)

Comment: Firebase is great =] Please put this somewhere on the site though - I personally spent like 4 hours trying to figure this out, reinstalling xcode, ruby, rebuilding my project from empty etc... Thanks!

Comment: I have just downloaded the iOS sample project and it still refers to FirebaseUI. Thought I would flag this so it can be updated as many people are now probably testing Firebase using the Google I/O videos